# How to use facebook sdk 4.0.0 with codeigniter?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

So I need to load Facebook library to use it with codeigniter... previous versions was simple - there were only 3 files

```
/application/libraries/facebook:

base_facebook.php
facebook.php
fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt
```

I would load facebook library and that would be it...
But now there are bunch of files so How to make it work with codeigniter?

Here is list of all files for the new facebook sdk as seen on github https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue and after a lot of trial and error, got it figured out. Basically, created a Facebook CI library that bridges the gap between the SDK. Wrote up a blog post about it: http://www.benmarshall.me/facebook-sdk-php-v4-codeigniter/

Not sure if it's the best implementation, but hopefully that will help!

Comment: Can't we do it without native PHP session? Is there any particular reason to initiate a PHP Session instead of CI Session?

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/puneetkay/Facebook-PHP-CodeIgniter

This repo is based on Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.3) and it's not difficult use the latest SDK with this base

Comment: Yes but I don't see how one would be able to use it with the latest SDK.. please see my updated question... thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't the polish way to do it... but I think it solves your problem.

Inside the `application/libraries/facebook/` create another lib like `facebook_package.php`.
Then you could include the standard facebook-sdk files like this:

```
<?php

class facebook_package {

    function __construct() {
    /**
     * Autoload Facebook SDK
     */
    $lib_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    require_once($lib_dir . '/FacebookSDKException.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/FacebookRequestException.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/FacebookCanvasLoginHelper.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/FacebookClientException.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/FacebookOtherException.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/FacebookPermissionException.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/FacebookRequest.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/FacebookResponse.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/FacebookServerException.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/FacebookSession.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/FacebookThrottleException.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/GraphObject.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/GraphLocation.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/GraphSessionInfo.php');
    require_once($lib_dir . '/GraphUser.php');
    }

}

?>
```

Be careful about the order cause it matters.

On your controller you could now simple done `$this->load->library('facebook/facebook_package');`

And start using the sdk. Try it with their example https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4 and don't forget to include in the top of your controller

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
```

Hope this help, I've got the same problem and this how I solved it quickly. Maybe there are some better ways to do it.